# Importing knowledge base from MD File

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

How can we fetch the QnA Pair from the URL which runs JS and then renders the DOM? The file is in markdown format and renders into HTML via running JS.

I came to know that the QnA Maker only searches the HTML contents. I want to have QnA pairs from a markdown file. For example:

- This works in QnA: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md
- While this not: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gulpjs/gulp/master/docs/FAQ.md

I am able to get the content as a second one from a page, but it's of no use as QnA doesn't support raw markdown. It supports in the form of HTML and the page I am requesting renders it after running JS.

I tried requesting with Postman too and body only contains Please enable JS and the same is happening with QnA.

Comment: Can you please show what you have done and what problem exactly do you have?

Comment: I came to know that the QnA Maker only searches the HTML contents. I want to have QnA pairs from a markdown file. For example:
This works in QnA: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md
While this not: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gulpjs/gulp/master/docs/FAQ.md
I am able to get the content as a second one from a page, but it's of no use as QnA doesn't support raw markdown. It supports in the form of HTML and the page I am requesting renders it after running JS. I tried requesting with Postman too and body only contains Please enable JS and the same is happening with QnA.

Comment: @Sumit update the question with the relevant information, don't post it as a comment. This question is too vague, just like your other one. There are no QnA pairs in Markdown. There are lists, headers, plain text. If you simply click on `Raw` on the links you provided you'll see that it's just level-2 headings and text

Comment: `as QnA doesn't support raw markdown` there's no non-raw Markdown. There's no Markdown in the form of HTML, it's just HTML that was probably generated by a markdown renderer, probably not. If your tool accepts HTML only, you have to provide it with HTML

Comment: BTW [QnA Maker's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-markdown-format) explain it *does* use Markdown, compatible with CommonMark.